# Fall detection feature of app work in series 4 apple watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

My watch app have fall detection feature however apple watch series 4 has default fall detection, so if default is enable would my feature work or not? Apple does not provide any framework to get default access or does it.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide a way to access fall detection.